# Turning off VS2012's automatic dns resolution when adding service reference

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to add a service reference to a WCF app hosted on our local intranet and VS2012 is automatically replacing the IP address I'm giving it with a resolved DNS name.

I would like to see:

```
 http://10.1.0.96/CrmTunnel.svc
```

but VS is populating all of the disco/svcinfo/wsdl files with:

```
 http://mlapp01.domain.com/CrmTunnel.svc
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I needed to add this to my web.config in the behavior section:

```
  <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
```